# Django chaining filters doesn't work

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to filter a ListView and I'm having some trouble chaining the filters.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
accounts = Accounts.objects.all()
if self.filter_form.cleaned_data['type']:
    accounts.filter(type=self.filter_form.cleaned_data['type'])
```

However the filter doesn't seem to chain and I end up with all the objects. I tried printing the query but it never changes. Am I doing something wrong? Can't filters be chained like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`accounts` still refers to `Accounts.objects.all()`. You need to reassign the name in order to point to the filtered query:

```
accounts = accounts.filter(type=self.filter_form.cleaned_data['type'])
```

Comment: *facepalm* just figured it out... such a silly mistake